# How to extract text and the xpath to that element of the HTML page in Python

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I am working on a Django project where I need to extract all the text-containing elements and the xPath to that element.
E.G:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        The Demo page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <section>
            <h1> Hello world
            </h1>
        </section>
        <div>
            <p>
                Hope you all are doing well,
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                This is the example HTML
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should be something like:

```
/head/title: The Demo Page
/body/div/section/h1: Hello world!
/body/div/div[1]/p: Hope you all are doing well,
/body/div/div[2]/p: This is the example HTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
from lxml import etree
html = """[your html above]"""

root = etree.fromstring(html)
targets = root.xpath('//text()[normalize-space()]/..')
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

for target in targets:
    print(tree.getpath(target),target.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
/html/head/title The Demo page
/html/body/div/section/h1 Hello world
/html/body/div/div[1]/p Hope you all are doing well,
/html/body/div/div[2]/p This is the example HTML
```

Comment: Your answer worked fine for the above HTML, but it is failing if the text in `<p>` tag is like `<div><p><span>This is the</span> example HTML</p></div>`

Comment: How can we get this text as `<span>This is the </span> example HTML`

Comment: @ShahidTariq First, there is no `<span>` in your sample html. Second, in any case, it's a different question and as per StackOverflow policy, you should probably post it as another question with the new sample html.

Comment: Thanks! but anyway it will be appreciated if you help to answer the question here itself.

Comment: @ShahidTariq I'm afraid not; the change you made with the edit to the question and the new question in your comment probably require a different approach to everything. As I said, it's best if you undo the edit to the original question and post a new one.

Comment: @ShahidTariq I'll definitely take a look. In the meantime, if we are done with this one, don't forget to accept the answer, please.